# Wordpress page URL goes to wrong page

Tags: wordpress

I have a weird issue. I am still somewhat new to WordPress and I have an issue that has me stumped.

I have been working on a site created by another developer. I have been fixing the site map by making sure that pages have the appropriate parents and proper permalinks.

I have a situation where I have a page with the following permalink:

http://passaicschools.org/school-no-2/anti-bullying-info/

The problem is that this link takes me to a different page with a different permalink:

http://passaicschools.org/school-no-1/anti-bullying-info/

I can't seem to figure out what is going on here. You can even type in the first url and it "redirects" (it looks like a redirect but I am not using that term in a technical sense).

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you check .httaccess file? or resetting the permalink?

Comment: Go to both page, open each page, edit your permalink just below the title and leave it blank and save it. Do this process for both the page as you have mentioned above. WordPress will default create permalink, you don't ned to insert. Save and see it once !!!

Comment: OK. I got it. Not sure why this happened but when I looked at the page in the list of pages, it was showing that it belonged to a different parent. The permalink was right, I know it was, but I guess something got mixed up in the database. I did a quick edit, reset the parent, and it worked... Whew! THANKS, your question gave me the idea.

Comment: Would you like to add a description as an answer with a description how you did this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I created a services page and when I added it to the top menu it kept automatically redirecting to the blog page.

All the permalinks were fine and nothing was set to have a parent page. I read an above comment and tried a reverse effect of actually giving the services page a parent (I made it the blog page it was automatically redirecting to) and then it went to the services page perfectly fine!

I'm not sure how or why this worked but it fixed the issue so I'll worry about permalink aesthetic later haha

Answer (score 0):

go to settings and then pages then set to link path

Comment: This does not help with the redirect issue. The link can be correct here, the site still redirects to the wrong page.